# Bases are looping using simplex method

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

The question is:

Maximize $x_1 − 2x_2 − 3x_3 − x_4$ subject to the constraints $x_j ≥ 0$ for all $j$ and

\begin{align}
x_1 − x_2 − 2x_3 − x_4 \le& 4 \\
2x_1 + x_3 − 4x_4 \le& 2 \\
−2x_1 + x_2 + x_4 \le& 1.
\end{align}

Adding slack variables I get:

\begin{align}
x_1 − x_2 − 2x_3 − x_4 + s_1 + 0s_2 + 0s_3 =& 4 \\
2x_1  + 0x_2 + x_3 − 4x_4 + 0s_1 +s_2 + 0s_3 =& 2 \\
−2x_1 + x_2 + 0x_3 + x_4 + 0s_1 + 0s_2 + s_3 =& 1.
\end{align}

Doing out my table I get:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
BASES&x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4&s_1&s_2&s_3&RHS \\ \hline
 &1&-2&-3&-1&0&0&0&0\\ \hline
s_1&1&-1&-2&-1&1&0&0&4\\ \hline
s_2&2&0&1&-4&0&1&0&2\\ \hline
s_3&-2&1&0&1&0&0&1&1\\ \hline
\end{array}

I choose to swap bases $x_1$ and $s_2$ since $x_1$ takes on the greatest coefficient in the objective function and $s_2$ basis row takes on the smallest non-negative ratio between RHS and and $x_1$. I get:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
BASES&x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4&s_1&s_2&s_3&RHS \\ \hline
 &0&2&\frac{7}{2}&-1&0&\frac{1}{2}&0&1\\ \hline
s_1&0&1&\frac{5}{2}&-1&-1&\frac{1}{2}&0&-3\\ \hline
x_1&1&0&\frac{1}{2}&-2&0&\frac{1}{2}&0&1\\ \hline
s_3&0&1&1&-3&0&1&1&3\\ \hline
\end{array}

Now $x_3$ holds the greatest coefficient and $x_1$ the smallest ratio since $1/\frac{1}{2} = 2 < 3$

Swapping those we get

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
BASES&x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4&s_1&s_2&s_3&RHS \\ \hline
 &7&-2&0&-13&0&3&0&6\\ \hline
s_1&5&-1&0&-9&1&2&0&13\\ \hline
x_3&2&0&1&-4&0&1&0&2\\ \hline
s_3&-2&1&0&1&0&0&1&1\\ \hline
\end{array}

Now we choose to swap $x_1$ in for the basis of $x_3$ since $x_1=7$ holds the largest value and $\frac{2}{2} = 1$ holds the smallest ratio.

From here we just keep swapping $x_1$ and $x_3$ indefinitely and the coefficients of the objective function never reach all-negative values.

Yet this seems to have a solution on linear programming calculators, so I must be doing something wrong. Does anyone know what?

Comment: Typo: in the 2nd tableau, $s_1 = 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some errors in the OP's steps.

1. In the initial tableau, at the row representing the objective function $z = x_1 − 2x_2 − 3x_3 − x_4$ (a.k.a. $z$-row), always *change the sign of coefficients*
   \begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
   \hline
   \text{bases} &x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4&s_1&s_2&s_3& \text{RHS} \\ \hline
    &\bf-1&\bf2&\bf3&\bf1&0&0&0&0\\ \hline
   s_1&1&-1&-2&-1&1&0&0&4\\ \hline
   s_2&2&0&1&-4&0&1&0&2\\ \hline
   s_3&-2&1&0&1&0&0&1&1\\ \hline
   \end{array}
   because

   - $z -(x_1 - 2x_2 - 3x_3 - x_4) = 0$  (To understand the row of the rightmost 0, you may think about $A {\bf x} + I_3 {\bf s} = {\bf b}$ on RHS.)
     \begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
     \hline
     \text{bases} &z&x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4&s_1&s_2&s_3& \text{RHS} \\ \hline
      &\bf1&\bf-1&\bf2&\bf3&\bf1&0&0&0&0\\ \hline
     s_1&\bf0&1&-1&-2&-1&1&0&0&4\\ \hline
     s_2&\bf0&2&0&1&-4&0&1&0&2\\ \hline
     s_3&\bf0&-2&1&0&1&0&0&1&1\\ \hline
     \end{array}
   - the coefficient of $z$ is *always* one, and it's *never* changed, so it's *omitted* (to save ink).
2. Choose only *negative* elements in the $z$-row.

   - Think of $z$ as an *affine* function of $x_1,\dots,x_4$.  In $z = x_1 − 2x_2 − 3x_3 − x_4$, it's natural to increase $x_1$ in order to maximize $z$.
   - This corresponds to choosing a *negative* entry at the $z$-row in the simplex tableau.  (We often choose the most negative one.)
     \begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
     \hline
     \text{bases} &x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4&s_1&s_2&s_3& \text{RHS} \\ \hline
      &\bf-1&2&3&1&0&0&0&0\\ \hline
     s_1&1&-1&-2&-1&1&0&0&4\\ \hline
     s_2&\bf2^*&0&1&-4&0&1&0&\bf2\\ \hline
     s_3&-2&1&0&1&0&0&1&1\\ \hline
     \end{array}
   - In this case, we replace $s_2$ with $x_1$.  (Denote this as $\{s_1,s_2,s_3\}\to\{s_1,x_1,s_3\}$ for short.)
3. As the RHS of a simplex tableau represents the current basic *feasible* solution (BFS, denoted as $\bf x_B$), it can *never* take a negative value.  (OP's second tableau row $s_1$ should be multiplied by -1.)
   \begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
   \hline
   \text{bases} &x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4&s_1&s_2&s_3& \text{RHS} \\ \hline &0&2&\frac{7}{2}&-1&0&\frac{1}{2}&0&1\\ \hline
   s_1&0&-1&-\frac{5}{2}&1^*&1&-\frac{1}{2}&0&\bf3\\ \hline
   x_1&1&0&\frac{1}{2}&-2&0&\frac{1}{2}&0&1\\ \hline
   s_3&0&1&1&-3&0&1&1&3\\ \hline
   \end{array}
4. At the $z$-row in the above tableau, the only negative entry -1 under $x_4$ is chosen, as well as the only positive entry 1 in the $x_4$ column.  Do a pivot operation at the entry marked with *.
   \begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
   \hline
   \text{bases} & x_1 & x_2 &           x_3 & x_4 & s_1 &      s_2 & s_3 & \text{RHS} \\ \hline
            &   0 &   1 &             1 &   0 &   1 &        0 &   0 &          4 \\ \hline
        x_4 &   0 &  -1 &      -\frac52 &   1 &   1 & -\frac12 &   0 &          3 \\ \hline
        x_1 &   1 &  -2 &      -\frac92 &   0 &   2 & -\frac12 &   0 &          7 \\ \hline
        s_3 &   0 &  -2 & -\frac{13}{2} &   0 &   3 & -\frac12 &   1 &         12 \\ \hline
   \end{array}
   Since every entry in the $z$-row is non-negative, we've done.

Hence, the optimal solution is $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = (7,0,0,3)$ with optimal value 4.

Comment: Very nice explanation, thanks!